# Weird horizontal and vertical lines in google chrome

Tags: google-chrome

The problem is that google chrome shows some weird vertical and horizontal lines in my website.
I think is a render problem but I'm not sure.

Google chrome version is 18.0.1025.168

You can visit the website here: http://www.plastic-data.com/hotel/

And here, the screenshoot:

[image]

And i have checked for extensions, my google chrome doesn't have any.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is not on the browser, neither on your website, I tested here on my installation of Google Chrome 18.0.1025.168, and no problems found as you can see on the image below:

[image]

**Note:**

I had that problem in the past, and was a graphic driver problem.

I believe that it is a graphic driver problem on the computer you are using!

Answer (score 9):

Mac with Chrome version 89.0.4389.90. The method @cybersholt and @Alex_J provided solved it for me (though the option is slightly different for Mac users):

1. Type chrome://flags in URL bar
2. Go to GPU rasterization (currently default).
3. Set to Disabled

Answer (score 3):

This worked for me..!

1) Type chrome://flags in URL bar

2) Click on "Reset all to default" at the top near to "search flags".

Answer (score 2):

I Hope the following steps work for you!

Follow the steps:-

1) Type chrome://flags in URL bar

2) Locate the following entry "Composited render layer borders"

3) Make sure it is set to "Enable"

4) Restart your browser and then check!!

Comment: On Mac OSX 10.8.2 with NVIDIA GeForce GT 650M 512 MB and this **did not** make any difference for me, for what it's worth. At the moment I have no info on my actual graphics driver...

Comment: This actually put (multi-colored) lines on basically every page for me.

Comment: I also had a similar problem, lines running at a 45 degree angle on solid backgrounds, in chrome flags I set 
GPU rasterization MSAA sample count to 0 & that fixed the problem.

Comment: @cybersholt this should be the top answer. Cheers.

Comment: @DrewRobertson93 it would seem with the launch of Chrome 63, my answer no longer works. Setting #gpu-rasterization-msaa-sample-count to a number >= 2 helps improve it but doesn't solve the problem.

Windows 10 1709 16299.98

Chrome 63.0.3239.84

Nvidia GeForce GTX 1060 6GB - Gigabyte

Answer (score 1):

I also had the same problem with 45° horizontal white dashed lines repeating on any website in chrome with a solid color background. It was happening on multiple computers with only using the chrome browser. @cybersholt solution fixed the problem.

1) Type chrome://flags in URL bar

2) Go to GPU rasterization MSAA sample count (which should be set to default).

3) Set to 0

Answer (score 0):

had the same problem. had to Disable this: 
1) Type chrome://flags in URL bar
2) Locate the following entry "Composited render layer borders".
BiG thanks for the tip!

Answer (score 0):

Just ran into this issue, although I had multicolored horizontal lines instead of vertical lines like this:

[image]

One of the comments described in [this post by @Cat-Friend](https://support.google.com/chrome/thread/38144053/weird-horizontal-lines-rendering-for-certain-webpages?hl=en) finally fixed the issue after much searching.

To fix this issue:

1. Open the Settings page in Chrome (`chrome://settings`)
2. Search for `hardware acceleration`
3. Disable Hardware Acceleration